# How can I add a gradient to a tab control background?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I have a tab-based application for windows, which I am developing by myself.

I would like to add a subtle gradient to the background of my tab control. How would I go around doing this? What is the best method for me to use?

I think that implementing a custom control that takes up the space of the tab control would work, but how would I then draw a gradient using GDI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use GDI you'll need the GradientFill function. You can also use GDI+ to get gradients. Here's a plain GDI example:

```
TRIVERTEX        vert[2] ;
GRADIENT_RECT    gRect;
vert [0] .x      = 0;
vert [0] .y      = 0;
vert [0] .Red    = 0x0000;
vert [0] .Green  = 0x0000;
vert [0] .Blue   = 0x0000;
vert [0] .Alpha  = 0x0000;

vert [1] .x      = 100;
vert [1] .y      = 32; 
vert [1] .Red    = 0x0000;
vert [1] .Green  = 0x0000;
vert [1] .Blue   = 0xff00;
vert [1] .Alpha  = 0x0000;

gRect.UpperLeft  = 0;
gRect.LowerRight = 1;
GradientFill(hdc,vert,2,&gRect,1,GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_H);
```

As for the tab control, you could sub-class the control and override its non-client and client drawing handlers to render the gradient.

To sub class a control, first create the control and then replace its WNDPROC function:

```
OldWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr (hControl, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)NewWndProc);
```

then, in your new WNDPROC:

```
NewWndProc (usual args)
{
  switch message
  {
  case paint:
    draw gradient
    return result

  default:
    return CallWindowProc (OldWndProc, ..args..); <- important!
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should put the `return CallWindowProc` call outside the switch, or the compiler might give a warning that "all control paths not returning..". +1 though, very extensive answer. And I did not know about the sub classing :)

Comment: Could you point me to the right message(s) to handle. WM_PAINT?

Comment: I tried WM_PAINT, but I need something specific to the client area.

Comment: @Alexander: The painting of the client area is handled by the client, so you'll need to add the gradient code to the child windows of the tab control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GDI+ LinearGradientBrush:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533914(VS.85).aspx

GDI+ is available in WinXP and later Windows versions, may be installed also on previous Windows versions. GDI+ SDK is part of Windows SDK.

Answer (score 1):

In the good old GDI, the [`GradientFill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144957%28VS.85%29.aspx) function does the gradient thing.